# Question about IPC

Tags: ipc

Hello and thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer to help me understand this

I'm curious about a 30.000 ft view on how IPC works in Linux between parent-child processes...I understand there's multiple types of IPC's... But I'm currently trying to figure out if parent-child process IPC communications go thru the API on the way to the kernel

For example... if the bash shell forks a ps command process... I'm assuming the ps process uses IPC to communicate the results back the the bash shell... If this is how it works I'm trying to figure out if it goes thru the API... I'm guessing it does but I can't find anything that specifically states that

Once again... thanks for any help anyone can offer me

Answer (score 3):

There is much less actual IPC in your example than you think.

When `bash` starts the `ps` command, the ps process inherits various things from its parent process: the file handles for standard input, standard output and standard error output; ulimit settings; environment variables; and the current working directory, to name a few.

The `ps` command just writes it output to the standard output filehandle, which normally points to the user's TTY device, which is the responsibility of the kernel's TTY driver. On a console session (whether a Linux virtual console or an actual serial console) this would connect directly to the user's screen; on modern systems, the TTY device is usually a pseudo-TTY slave device, which leads back to another process: that process might be a terminal emulator program on a local GUI desktop, or `sshd` for remote logins. The `bash` shell that started the `ps` command won't be involved at all in this.

The only Inter-Process Communication between `bash` and `ps` in your example is a fairly trivial one: when the `ps` process ends, it will initially go to a "zombie" state: the process memory is released, and its only remains will be the process table slot and the return code the `ps` process produced on exit.

The kernel will send a SIGCHLD signal to the zombie's parent, the `bash` process, which is `wait(2)`ing for it. Once `bash` gets the signal, it will also receive the return code the `ps` process produced when it ended. The shell will place it into the special shell variable `$?`, and either output a new command prompt or continue the script it was running (if the `ps` command was started from a script).

Meanwhile, as the return code is now successfully delivered to the parent process, the kernel frees up the process table slot that the `ps` used to occupy; and so the zombie process has been laid to rest.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply!  It helps me develop a better understanding of Linux... I hope you don't mind one more question to clarify my understanding of IPC... When processes do communicate with IPC... Does the processes have to go thru the API?  My mental picture of the process is: the process communicates to the API... the API passes the message/data to the kernel... the kernel passes it to the IPC... and then the process is reversed on it's way to the other process.... How close am I to how it actually works with this?  Once again... Thanks for the reply!